# Cut/paste stopped working in xterm (&UXterm) after upgrading to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, xterm

I seem to no longer be able to copy text, (eg; from a web page; "sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-gtk appmenu-q") and paste it into a terminal window. Right click (and alt-rt click, ctrl-rt-click), only highlights sections of the terminal window of gives me the "minimize, ......" menu w/o a copy or paste option listed. It worked fine pre 11.0.. Clue? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Workaround seems to be to run the straight gnome "terminal". It's not quite as functional but seems to be sufficient for now. If anyone knows how to enable the buffer to be able to paste into an xterm, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of methods of copy and pasting when using xterm.

**To paste** you can press `Shift` + `Insert`

Or click the middle button on your mouse (if you only have two mouse buttons then pressing both at the same time will simulate a middle click)

**To copy** highlight the text you want to copy and press `Shift` + `Insert`

Or highlight the text to copy and click the middle mouse button (or if you only have a two button mouse click both together)