# restore shutdown button on taskbar? How do you restore desktop taskbar in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, restore, taskbar

Isn't there a way to go back to a default setting for the desktop? An original configuration? How about restoring the shutdown/logoff button in the panel/taskbar?

Just installed Lubuntu (Ubuntu 13.10) and got to playing around with the settings. Unfortunately, I took some things out and moved things around that now that I look at it I really don't like.

How do I get back to square one, the way the desktop task bar looked like when I first installed it?

Example I lost the "start" like area in the left. the 3 icons to the right of that and now don't have he power button which was all the way to the right where the clock is. I don't really want to re-install OS all over again, because I do want to keep some customizations that I have done.

Comment: Thanks Stormvirux! To the other NOOBS like me- please reads the comments below. i was having issues copying and pasting into terminal and I didn't understand a message that was displayed after one of the commands that I pasted, but all is good now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the default config

```
sudo cp /usr/share/lxpanel/profile/Lubuntu/panels/panel ~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels
```

Change `owner:group` to the local account from root.

```
sudo chown owner:group  ~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels/panel
```

now restart the panel

```
lxpanelctl restart
```

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1490938&p=9557050#post9557050)

Comment: How do I copy and paste these instructions into the terminal? I tried ctrl-c, v and shift-ctrl-c, v into xterm and UXterm (what is the difference?) and neither work. In the past I was typing the commands, but This one seems much longer and I wan to make sure I get it right.

Comment: see these on how to copy paste in xterm.. http://askubuntu.com/questions/68214/cut-paste-stopped-working-in-xterm-uxterm-after-upgrading-to-11-10?rq=1

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/237942/how-does-copy-paste-work-with-xterm#

Comment: That was GREAT! thanks! I am now using LXTerminal 0.1.11 which has the file, edit, tabs, etc. and it has the paste function as well. how do I find the user group for this: Change owner:group to the local account from root.

sudo chown owner:group  ~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels/panel right now I get chown: invalid user

Comment: I have tried using Mike and mike in owner:mike the only name of pc and it doesn't work. If it helps this is the first command line in the terminal 

mike@mike-OLD-HP-Compaq-nc6120-PT596AA-ABA:

Comment: just execute what is given directly ..No need to change anything

Comment: OK I was confused by the "invalid comment. Ill try it again.